# Moving from xml to Annotations

Tags: java, spring

I am migrating to Spring 3 from 2.5 and would like to use annotations to inject my beans. I could not figure out how do I create use annotations to achieve the following

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="#{configLoader.getSmtpServer()}" />
    <property name="username" value="#{configLoader.getSmtpUsername()}" />
    <property name="password" value="#{configLoader.getSmtpPassword()}" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- A properties file based configuration bean -->
<bean id="propConfiguration" class="org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration">
    <property name="delimiterParsingDisabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="file" value="classpath:configuration.#{systemProperties.CONFIG_MODE}.properties"/>
    <property name="reloadingStrategy" ref="reloadingStrategy"/>
</bean>

<!-- The managed reloading strategy for the configuration bean -->
<bean id="reloadingStrategy" class="org.apache.commons.configuration.reloading.FileChangedReloadingStrategy">
    <property name="refreshDelay" value="30000"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: If you google "spring configuration annotations" you'll get about a bazillion hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a bean or beans annotated with `@Configuration`. Then instantiate everything in Java just as our ancestors did before Spring.

So for example:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    public ReloadingStrategy reloadingStrategy() {
        strategy = new FileChangedReloadingStrategy();
        strategy.setRefreshDelay(30000);
        return strategy;
    }
}
```

Then do the same for your other dependencies.

To reference a bean defined in one configuration class in another, just use `@Autowired`.